# Mini DP and DVI Conversion

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, mini-dv

Video card is: AMD HD 6950
My video card comes with 1xHDMI, 2xDVI, and 2xMini DP ports.

I have always used VGA and DVI only.   I have the HDMI already connected.  I want to hook up 2 more display.

One of the display can take a VGA only, the other is an LCD TV so it has VGA, HDMI, Component.  I am wondering:

1) What is the best output port to use for the second two monitors? The miniDP 1.2 or the DVI?
2) I need to run a long cable maybe 15-25 feet, this might change the answer to question 1, is  an HDMI long cable 20+ ft going to be better than a 20ft DVI or miniDV ?

Comment: What card do you have? Just because it has many connectors does not mean it can drive all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I readily presume the card has two mini *DP* ie. mini DisplayPort ports. I will also freely presume this is a Radeon card. There are two "clocks" on your card and the video signal you carry over a DVI or a HDMI port is a) the same kind just a different physical interface (with HDMI being able to carry audio as well) b) needs a clock. If you want a third clock you need to supply it yourself. Such thing is called an "active DisplayPort to DVI converter". You want a "single link" one for 30 dollars not a "dual link" for 100 dollars.

The cable doesnt matter but these days the easiest and cheapest is to get is a long HDMI cable.  HDMI - DVI converter are less than a dollar on eBay (or monoprice where you could get your nice long HDMI for cheap as well).

Edit: DisplayPort monitors do not need clocks.